# Deployment failing due to exception in JBoss server

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

While deploying war file in JBoss server getting following exception. But couldn't find any thing. I'm not sure what exactly the root cause of this issue.

Why Jobss throwing this exception?

**ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:**

```
    --- Incompletely deployed packages ---
    org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@be4f5568 { url=file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/deploy/integrationserver.war }
      deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
      status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/tmp/deploy/tmp29469integrationserver-exp.war/ deployment failed
     state: FAILED
      watch: file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/deploy/integrationserver.war
     altDD: null
      lastDeployed: 1409880646720
    lastModified: 1409880645000
      mbeans:

    --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
    ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=integrationserver.war,id=-1102097048
      State: FAILED
      Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/tmp/deploy/tmp29469integrationserver-exp.war/ deployment failed

     --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
     ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=integrationserver.war,id=-1102097048
       State: FAILED
      Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/tmp/deploy/tmp29469integrationserver-exp.war/ deployment failed

Full Stack Trace

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | 07:00:50,383 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | 07:00:50,383 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/services] startup failed due to previous errors
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | 07:00:50,412 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | 07:00:50,484 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.web.deployment:war=integrationserver.war,id=-1102097048
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/home/blrproj/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/tmp/deploy/tmp29469integrationserver-exp.war/ deployment failed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:379)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(Ab
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | send a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | Received a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | Send a packet PING : ok
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | stractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | 07:00:50,517 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/home/blrproj/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/clubcar/deploy/integrationserver.war
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 | org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/home/user/apps/jboss-4.2.0.GA/server/dev/tmp/deploy/tmp29469integrationserver-exp.war/ deployment failed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:379)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.inv`enter code here`oke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/09/05 07:00:50 |   at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBe
```

Comment: How could we without the full logging output

Comment: with JBoss failed deployments there usually is a specific error somewhere before the "summary" that you posted here.

Comment: Edited post and added full stack trace